# Cloning multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, clone, raku

I want to clone a multidimensional array `@a` to an array `@b`.

I've proceeded with the most intuitive way and I came up with the following:

```
    my @a = [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0];

    my @b = @a.clone;

    @a[0][1] = 1;
    @b[1][0] = 1;

    say '@a : ' ~ @a.gist;
    say '@b : ' ~ @b.gist;
```

and the print out is:

```
    @a : [[0 1 0] [1 0 0] [0 0 0]]
    @b : [[0 1 0] [1 0 0] [0 0 0]]
```

That means that the two arrays @a and @b are binded?

Questions:

1. Why array @a is binded to array @b (What is the purpose of the clone
   method in this situation? We know that clone behave as intented for
   one-dimensional arrays)
2. How can I really clone @a to @b (multidimensional)?
3. Which is the most efficient way (time bounded) to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you have is not a multi-dimensional array, but rather an array of arrays. Since `clone` is shallow, it will just copy the top-level array. In this case, the `clone` is also redundant, since assignment into an array is already a copying operation.

A simple fix is to clone each of the nested arrays:

```
my @b = @a.map(*.clone);
```

Alternatively, you could use a real multi-dimensional array. The declaration would look like this:

```
my @a[3;3] = [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0];
```

And then the copying into another array would be:

```
my @b[3;3] = @a;
```

The assignments also need updating to use the multi-dimensional syntax:

```
@a[0;1] = 1;
@b[1;0] = 1;
```

And finally, the result of this:

```
say '@a : ' ~ @a.gist;
say '@b : ' ~ @b.gist;
```

Is as desired:

```
@a : [[0 1 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]]
@b : [[0 0 0] [1 0 0] [0 0 0]]
```

As a final cleanup, you can also "pour" an conceptually infinite sequence of `0`s into the array to initialize it:

```
my @a[3;3] Z= 0 xx *;
```

Which means that the 3x3 structure does not need to be replicated on the right.

Comment: OK. Got it.

So when i try to change @a[0][1] then in reality i change the Scalar @a[0] (which is an array), in that case the second value of the array.
And when i change @b[1][0] in reality i change the Scalar content of @b[1].
And because the clone method makes a shallow copy of the array @a, both arrays @a and @b have as content the same 3 Scalars which are arrays.
That's why i get the same result when i print out the two arrays at the end!

Is that Correct?

Comment: @ikarpenis @Larry use scalar (lowercase 's') in [the wikipedia sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)) and `Scalar` (uppercase 'S') to mean [Raku's standard built in scalar *container*](https://docs.raku.org/type/Scalar). A `Scalar` is never an array; but it can *contain* (a reference to) an `Array`. An assignment `@a[0][1] = ...` doesn't change the scalar or `Scalar` `@a[0]`, and doesn't put a new `Array` in the `Scalar` container `@a[0]` either. It just changes the value held in the 2nd `Scalar` in the existing `Array` held in the existing `Scalar` bound to `@a[0]`.

Answer (score 5):

`@a` and `@b` are not **bound**. They just happen to contain the same things. The `clone` does not recurse and only clones the outer Array.

One way to achieve what you want would be

```
@b = @a.map: *.clone;
```